# Thread was being aborted using TransmitFile

Tags: c#, error-handling, http-response-codes

There are a ton of threads Stackoverflow about this error, but none of them seem to help me solve my problem.

I'm transferring a small Excel file from server to client. My code:

```
protected void SaveSpreadsheet(string filePath)
{
    FileInfo myfile = new FileInfo(filePath);
    if (myfile.Exists)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myfile.Name);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myfile.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "xlsx";
        Response.TransmitFile(myfile.FullName);
        Response.End();
        //  Delete the file from the server
        if (File.Exists(strSaveFilePath))
        {
            File.Delete(strSaveFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the 'Thread was being aborted' error. I know from troubleshooting that the Response.End(); line is the problem.

A lot of the problems associated with this error are from people using Response.Redirect, but those solutions don't seem work for me. According to Microsoft, [replacing that line with HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312629) was their solution, but that gives me another error.

Many of the solutions on this and other sites recommend moving this code outside my Try-Catch block. I tried that, but the last part of my code (deleting the file) does not work, so I know I'm still getting an error.

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling response.end and then have code after it? Response.end aborts the thread as you see.

Comment: dman, you caught a good point, I've been working on complicated solutions and didn't catch that detail. But my problem remains, I can't execute my delete-file code. I'd still love to know how to prevent that error.

Comment: So use the obvious solution and move that code *before* the Response.End() call.

Comment: Hans, thanks. Tried that, gave me an error. What I'm really after here is for somebody to tell me how to prevent this error.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling Response.End. It aborts a thread which will throw a threadabortedception. It's not an "error" it's what the function does.

Comment: dman, thanks, but my code won't work without it. The Save Dialog box won't appear. As I said in my post, Microsoft suggested a replacement, but that didn't work either. I can see that Response.End is my problem, but can you tell me how to make this code snippet work without it?